# Providing input to another program using Console Application

Tags: c#, input, automation

my question would be, how do I provide input to another program? Specifically, I have a C# code, and all it does is pressing down the "W" button virtually. In a game, that means moving forward. So how do I combine them to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not in the way you are thinking.

The *closest* thing you will get is the `SendMessage` function and send [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the other process. Unfortunately, that's part of the Win32 API so you will have to do a *bunch* of PInvoke to get it. You can find the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you can spawn the process, you can redirect STDIN to a stream you can write to, which would simulate this for *some* programs. A sample can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Easier solution, start the game, put a weight on your "W" key :)